# How to Prepare an ADO.NET Statement which includes an NText (clob) parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, blob

I'm updating an existing application which uses a factory to build prepared statements, and then execute them later, which works for the rest of the system, but I've been tasked with adding a call to a statement which uses an `NText`, and I cannot figure out how to properly prepare the statement.  I am getting a runtime error of:

> SqlCommand.Prepare method requires all variable length parameters to have an explicitly set non-zero Size.

but I'm not sure what value to use for the `Length`?

Code sample:

```
SqlCommand update = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Log.Response_File_Log " +
  "SET File = @File " +
  ", DateFileReceived = GETDATE() " +
  "WHERE RunID = @RunID", _connection);
update.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@File", SqlDbType.NText));
update.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RunID", SqlDbType.Int));
update.Prepare();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `NTEXT`, is a [deprecated type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx). If your database has an `NTEXT` column change it to `VARBINARY(MAX)`. Use -1 for `MAX` type parameters length: `(...,SqlDbType.Varbinary, -1)`.

Answer (score -1):

Can you set it to the length of the data you're passing in to @File parameter? This is just a suggestion.