# how to use the N character in my C# command to make my program update Arabic Fields

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

//how to use the N character to make my program update Arabic Fields (first name ="الاسم الاول")...
   I mean

```
UPDATE  students SET first_name = N'الاسم' , last_name = N'الاسم الاخير' , father_name = N'الاسم الاخير' , mother_name = '', birth_date = '1/1/1990 12:00:00 AM' , education_level = '' , address = '' , notes = '' WHERE student_id = 33
```

//this command in MSSQL-Server but I am trying to use the UPDATE command in my C# program

```
 public string student(int id, string first_name, string last_name, string father_name, string mother_name, DateTime birth_date, string education_level, string address, 
         int[] phone_numbers, int[] old_phone_numbers, string notes)
    {
        SqlConnection SQLconnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand command = SQLconnection.CreateCommand();
        SQLconnection.Open();
        command.CommandText = "UPDATE  students SET " +
        "first_name = " + "'" + first_name + "'" + " , last_name = " + "'" + last_name + "'" +
         " , father_name = " + "'" + father_name + "'" + " , mother_name = " + 
        "'" + mother_name + "'" + ", birth_date = " + "'" + birth_date + "'" +
        " , education_level = " + "'" + education_level + "'"  +
        " , address = " + "'" + address + "'" + " , notes = " + "'" + notes + "'" +
        " WHERE student_id = " + id ;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SQLconnection.Close();
```

//is there a better and clear way better than these syntax ?

Comment: What do you mean by "The N character" ? and by the way this is an awful way to commit SQL statements. Use [Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) instead

Comment: SQLCommand.Parameters! Need to read about SQL Injection and why not to write SQL code in that way. (N character, I suspect means NVarchar or NChar on the database, to support the unicode strings)

Comment: like when you use the command in the SQL-Server :

Comment: UPDATE  students SET first_name = N'الاسم' , last_name = N'الاسم الاخير' , father_name = N'الاسم الاخير' , mother_name = '', birth_date = '1/1/1990 12:00:00 AM' , education_level = '' , address = '' , notes = '' WHERE student_id = 33

Comment: Did you ever think about what happens if somebody puts a `'` character in the notes?

Comment: no I do not, but what is the best syntax to use

Comment: What if one of your student's name's was `Robert'); DROP TABLE students;--`? :) Or, [little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) as they call him.

Comment: OMG so what is the solution to this problem?

Comment: is there a way to use  parameterised queries ?

Comment: See something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221196/how-to-prepare-an-ado-net-statement-which-includes-an-ntext-clob-parameter for an example of something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best method would be to use [Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx). Like this:

```
command.CommandText = @"UPDATE  students SET 
first_name = @first_name, 
last_name = @last_name,
//... and so on...
WHERE student_id = @id";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first_name", first_name);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last_name", last_name);
//... and so no...
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
```