# Reading ntext columns

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

I have a DB with column that contains a ntext field when you using a simple select query I get back only first 8000 bytes. How can I get all of the data inside ?

Comment: `NTEXT` is [deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx).

Comment: How are you getting the data currently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Tim Schmelter commented `NTEXT` is deprecated so best not to use it. The answer to the following question provides a suggestion as to what to use instead:

[How to Prepare an ADO.NET Statement which includes an NText (clob) parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221196/how-to-prepare-an-ado-net-statement-which-includes-an-ntext-clob-parameter)

If it is still necessary to use `NTEXT` then the following MSDN article might be of use:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175547(v=sql.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175547%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)